# JavaScript Objects Limit Size?

Tags: javascript

Surely I'm doing something wrong, but i can't realize what?
My problem is that I'm doing an AJAX request, i get the response, but when I'm going to put it inside a JavaScript object it fails, if the size is a little big. No matter if I try JSON or XML. Here is my code, i would appreciate so much any kind of help:

```
function DataFlow (Target, Txt, Tid, Rid){  
    var httpObj, obj, row, htm, col, par;
    this.tid = Tid;
    this.rid = Rid;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        httpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else
        window.alert ("Navegador nao suporta AJAX");        

    if (httpObj) {
        httpObj.onreadystatechange = function (){
            var txt, nrow;
            if (this.readyState == 4){
                if (this.status != 200)
                    window.alert ("Pagina nao encontrada: " + Target);
                else {  
                    txt = httpObj.responseText;
                    if (txt == null){
                        window.alert ("Sem Resposta");
                        return;
                    }

                    window.alert ("Size: " + txt.length + " bytes");
                    //No Problems Here
                    obj = eval ('(' + txt + ')');
                            //Sintaxe Error for Eval or XML for sizes over 300Kb
                    if (obj == null)
                        window.alert ("JSON!");

            }
        };
        httpObj.open("POST", Target, true);
        httpObj.send(Txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does fail means? what says your console?

Comment: I put some comments in my code

Comment: This could be a restriction on the server side. You get an error because the data you receive has been truncated. How big is big here anyway?

Comment: What is the content of `txt`? If you are trying to evaluate something you need to make sure it is a valid javascript.

Comment: It is a JSON... it works finely for sizes under 300kb

Comment: the var txt gets all the stuff... but when i put in the js obj it crashes.... So the problem cant be the server... I change the contend to display txt and its OK

Comment: Sorry for this question... I realized what was the problem... At the row 384 of my query I had an ' what makes JSON be invalid... I apologize and puts this comment...